# How to convert a json array of clob into a object type in Oracle (12.1) stored procedure

Tags: json, oracle, stored-procedures, clob

I am trying to convert a json array to json clob and the convert it object type in an Oracle stored procedure.

Below is the object type I have in Oracle.

```
create or replace TYPE REPORT_OBJ FORCE as OBJECT (
  id NUMBER,
  name NUMBER,
  createDt Date,
  value NUMBER(10,2)
);

create or replace TYPE REPORT_OBJ_LIST as TABLE OF REPORT_OBJ;
```

This is my json array:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"john",:"createDt":"01-jan-2020","value":10},
{"id":2,"name":"crystal","createDt":"01-feb-2020","value":20},
{"id":3,"name":"bob","createDt":"01-mar-2020","value":30}]
```

This is my stored procedure which takes report_obj_list as input parameter

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SaveUpdate_ReportsData(reportList IN REPORT_OBJ_LIST)
AS v_count number;
v_column REPORTS_DATA.id%TYPE;
updatedRecs Number;
recsCount Number;
dbid REPORTS_DATA.Id%TYPE;
dbname REPORTS_DATA.name%TYPE;
dbcreateDt REPORTS_DATA.createDt%TYPE;
dbvalue REPORTS_DATA.value%TYPE;
BEGIN
recsCount := 0;
updatedRecs := 0;
for i in reportList.first..reportList.last loop
v_column := 0;
dbid := 0;
dbname := 0;
dbcreateDt := sysdate;
dbvalue := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT NVL(b.repId,0) into v_column  from (
    (SELECT 'TEMP' as temp from REPORTS_DATA) a left join (
    SELECT DISTINCT 'TEMP' AS temp, NVL(id,0) as repId FROM REPORTS_DATA
    where createDt = reportList(i).createDt ) b on a.temp = b.temp);
        if(v_column <= 0 ) then 
            INSERT INTO REPORTS_DATA (Id,name,createDt,value)        
            VALUES (reportList(i).Id,reportList(i).name, reportList(i).createDt,
                reportList(i).value);
            updatedRecs := updatedRecs+1;
        else 
            updatedRecs := updatedRecs+1;

            SELECT id,name,createDt,value INTO 
                dbid,dbname,dbcreateDt,dbvalue
                FROM REPORTS_DATA
             where createDt = reportList(i).createDt;

            update REPORTS_DATA set id = NVL(reportList(i).id,dbid), 
                name = NVL(reportList(i).name,dbname) ,
                createDt = NVL(reportList(i).createDt,dbcreateDt),
                value = NVL(reportList(i).value, dbvalue);
     end if;
     EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
v_column := null;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello' || v_column);
    END;
    end loop;
      Commit;
     recsCount:= updatedRecs ;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELOOwq ' || recsCount);
end SaveUpdate_ReportsData ;
below is the oracle table

create table REPORTS_DATA(
id number,
name varchar(200),
createdt date,
value number(10,2)
);
```

From java, I have to convert jsonarray as clob (so that it can accept large amount of data as input to stored procedure), and the stored procedure should accept json array of clob and convert it to 'Report_obj_list', and from there the existing stored procedure will work fine. I have written the stored procedure which accepts object but i need to make changes so that it accepts clob json array and converts that to object inside the stored procedure.

Updated stored procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SaveUpdate_ReportsData(intnum in Number)
AS v_count number;
jstr clob;
reportList report_obj_list;
v_column REPORTS_DATA.id%TYPE;
dbid REPORTS_DATA.Id%TYPE;
dbname REPORTS_DATA.name%TYPE;
dbcreateDt REPORTS_DATA.createDt%TYPE;
dbvalue REPORTS_DATA.value%TYPE;
BEGIN
jstr := to_clob('[{"id":1,"name":"john","createDt":"01-jan-2020","value":10},
{"id":2,"name":"crystal","createDt":"01-feb-2020","value":20},
{"id":3,"name":"bob","createDt":"01-mar-2020","value":30}]');

select report_obj(id, name, to_date(createdt, 'dd-mon-yyyy'), value) 
  bulk collect into reportList
  from json_table(jstr, '$[*]'
                        columns( id       number        path '$.id',
                                 name    varchar2(20)  path '$.name',
                                 createdt varchar2(11)  path '$.createDt',
                                 value   number(10, 2) path '$.value'
                               )
                 );
for i in reportList.first..reportList.last loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('name_ ' || reportList(i).name);
v_column := 0;
dbid := 0;
dbname := 0;
dbcreateDt := sysdate;
dbvalue := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT NVL(b.repId,0) into v_column  from (
    (SELECT 'TEMP' as temp from REPORTS_DATA) a left join (
    SELECT DISTINCT 'TEMP' AS temp, NVL(id,0) as repId FROM REPORTS_DATA
    where createDt = reportList(i).createDt ) b on a.temp = b.temp);
        if(v_column <= 0 ) then 
            INSERT INTO REPORTS_DATA (Id,name,createDt,value)        
            VALUES (reportList(i).Id,reportList(i).name, reportList(i).createDt,
                reportList(i).value);
        else 
            SELECT id,name,createDt,value INTO 
                dbid,dbname,dbcreateDt,dbvalue
                FROM REPORTS_DATA
             where createDt = reportList(i).createDt;

            update REPORTS_DATA set id = NVL(reportList(i).id,dbid), 
                name = NVL(reportList(i).name,dbname) ,
                createDt = NVL(reportList(i).createDt,dbcreateDt),
                value = NVL(reportList(i).value, dbvalue);
     end if;
     EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
v_column := null;
    END;
    end loop;
      Commit;
end SaveUpdate_ReportsData ;
```

and i am calling the stored procedure as below:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  SaveUpdate_ReportsData(
   12
  );
END;
/
```

It's not throwing any type of error, but at the same time its not inserting the data into the REPORTS_DATA table not even printing the name.

Help me solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "my json array"? Certainly not the technical definition; what you posted is not a valid JSON string. Did you mean that the top-level structure is an array, made up of JSON objects? It seems that way, but you wrote just the opposite - an object whose members are arrays (just values, no attribute names - which makes it invalid).

Comment: Hi, i am sorry I have given an invalid jsonarray,I have updated the jsonarray and I was referring to the jsonarray as my jsonarray. I want to convert jsonarray to a object type in oracle which is of same structure(jsonarray structure including attribute names and order) in oracle. I have edited my jsonarray in the code

Comment: You still have an errant colon in the first object in the array - I removed it for the answer below.

Comment: For the modified question: Please remove the EXCEPTION section entirely and re-run. What happens now? (The EXCEPTION section swallows up the errors, so you are not going to see them - and therefore you won't be able to debug.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can extract the data from a JSON (in CLOB data type) and pass it to a collection (nested table) of objects of user-defined type, like you have. The PL/SQL code is for a function that accepts a CLOB (assumed to be valid JSON) and returns a nested table of objects. (Then I show one example of invoking the function in SQL, to see what was saved in it.)

Not sure what you mean by converting your JSON array to CLOB. As far as Oracle is concerned, the JSON ***is*** a CLOB.

Anyway - here is the function:

```
create or replace type report_obj force as object (
  id       number,
  name_    varchar2(20),
  createdt date,
  value_   number(10,2)
);
/

create or replace type report_obj_list as table of report_obj;
/

create or replace function json_to_obj_list (jstr clob)
  return report_obj_list
as
  lst report_obj_list;
begin
  select report_obj(id, name_, to_date(createdt, 'dd-mon-yyyy'), value_) 
  bulk collect into lst
  from json_table(jstr, '$[*]'
                        columns( id       number        path '$.id',
                                 name_    varchar2(20)  path '$.name',
                                 createdt varchar2(11)  path '$.createDt',
                                 value_   number(10, 2) path '$.value'
                               )
                 );
  return lst;
end;
/
```

(As you can see, I changed your object type definition - I changed the attribute names `name` and `value` to `name_` and `value_`, because `name` and `value` are Oracle keywords so they shouldn't be used as identifiers.)

And here is how this works. Note that I am passing an explicit CLOB to the function. More likely, you will want to store your CLOBs somewhere (table?) and pass them from there. That part is relatively trivial.

```
select * from json_to_obj_list(
to_clob(
'[{"id":1,"name":"john","createDt":"01-jan-2020","value":10},
{"id":2,"name":"crystal","createDt":"01-feb-2020","value":20},
{"id":3,"name":"bob","createDt":"01-mar-2020","value":30}]')
);

        ID NAME_                CREATEDT        VALUE_
---------- -------------------- ----------- ----------
         1 john                 01-jan-2020         10
         2 crystal              01-feb-2020         20
         3 bob                  01-mar-2020         30
```

Note that `createdt` is in fact `date` data type; in the output it looks like your inputs only because I intentionally set my `nls_date_format` to match it. Otherwise your query will return the dates in that column in whatever format is the default for your session.

Comment: Thank you @mathguy for quick response. I applied the logic you have provided in the above stored procedure, it did compiled without any exceptions but surprisingly it didn't insert any records in the table.I am new to this, i couldn't understand what is the issue, why its unable to insert the data into the table. I have updated the above stored with the logic you provided, if you dont mind will you please help me in understanding the issue

Comment: @kavya - "Empty output" when working with JSON often means that you are navigating the JSON incorrectly. I was getting empty output also at first, until I noticed the capitalization in your JSON: You have **createDt** with capital D, I had written **createdt**. JSON is case sensitive, key names in paths must match what is in the JSON exactly, including capitalization. Easy to miss.